# How does this array indexer helps coalesced memory access?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, ram

At [here](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/6bfac481aae4057ea887d42eb0f24371e9b4c4f9/native/src/seal/util/common.h#L420), it is defined this function:

```
        template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<is_uint32_v<T> || is_uint64_v<T>>>
        inline T reverse_bits(T operand, int bit_count)
        {
            // Just return zero if bit_count is zero
            return (bit_count == 0) ? T(0)
                                    : reverse_bits(operand) >> (sizeof(T) * static_cast<std::size_t>(bits_per_byte) -
                                                                static_cast<std::size_t>(bit_count));
        }
```

At a [later point](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/6bfac481aae4057ea887d42eb0f24371e9b4c4f9/native/src/seal/util/ntt.cpp#L284), this function is used to store elements in a scrambled way into an array:

```
inv_root_powers_[reverse_bits(i - 1, coeff_count_power_) + 1].set(power, modulus_);
```

The justification for this is so that the memory access is coalesced. However, I don't know why such random values would make it easier for the memory access. For example, here are some values:

```
reverse_bits(3661, 12) +1 = 2856
reverse_bits(3662, 12) +1 = 1832
reverse_bits(3663, 12) +1 = 3880
reverse_bits(3664, 12) +1 = 168
reverse_bits(3665, 12) +1 = 2216
reverse_bits(3666, 12) +1 = 1192
reverse_bits(3667, 12) +1 = 3240
reverse_bits(3668, 12) +1 = 680
reverse_bits(3669, 12) +1 = 2728
```

seems like things are stored far apart.

Comment: There is a 1 parameter version of `reverse_bits(operand)` somewhere

Comment: Please, don't use `=` in code blocks in a C++ question to mean "is equal".

Comment: @RichardCritten this is just the MSB to LSB reversion and etc so 1010 is 0101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right - the accesses you see in `NTTTables::initialize` are random-access and not serial. It is slower because of this "scramble". However, most of the work happens only later in [`DWTHandler::transform_to_rev`](https://github.com/microsoft/SEAL/blob/48a76398d9d1cadb67cdb73143fde03077d035c3/native/src/seal/util/dwthandler.h#L94), when the transform itself is applied.

There, they need to access the roots by reverse-bits order. The array being pre-scrambled means all the accesses to this array are now serial: you can see this in the `r = *++roots;` lines.

The reverse-bits access pattern has a good, real reason - it's because they're doing a variant of the Finite Fourier Transform (FFT). The memory access patterns used in those algorithms (sometimes called butterflies) are done in a bit-reverse order.

Comment: what do you mean by "serialized"?

Comment: I meant "are now serial", sorry for the confusion.